# Error using exception handling in python

Tags: python, exception, try-except

I just started learning python, while using the ***try*** command in exception handling, I got an syntax error

Here is my code,

```
def divide(a,b):
    {
        print(a," hello world", b)
        try:
            return a/b
        except:
            print("It is meaningless")
    }
print(divide(1,2))
```

Here is my output,

```
PS D:\python> python firstprog.py
  File "firstprog.py", line 4
    try:
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Why are there curly brackets???

Comment: This is bad function design.  Not all control paths return a value.  Either way this is just a typo.

Comment: If there weren't any curly brackets it will work as expected

Comment: @user3483203 Defaultly return `None`

Comment: @ausk like I said, bad function design.  Explicit > implicit.

Comment: I got the output once i removed the curly braces.. but how?

Comment: @GowthamKarnan Because curly braces are used for dictionaries and sets

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First remove your **curly braces**, curly braces in python are used for dictionaries/sets shorthand declaration.

like:

```
def divide(a,b):
    print(a," hello world", b)
    try:
        return a/b
    except:
        print("It is meaningless")

print(divide(1,2))
```

because with curly braces and a colon python is thinking it is some sort of dictionary and throwing an error near try.

Comment: Please avoid answering this kind of questions, it doesn't make sense i did the same thing, i answered the question but quickly deleted it because i realized that answering this kind of questions don't make sense

Comment: Note that semicolon is allowed

Comment: What kind of question are you expecting from a new comer. Not every one is so experienced to ask high level questions. In your experience this question is redundant, in mine the highest voted so question is headless because branch prediction is taught in CS 2nd year.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention if there are this kind of questions write it in the comments, okay?

Comment: I ellaborated on why curly braces will not work. if he had written like `def divide(a,b):
    {print('a'): print('b')}` the code would have run successfully